# ASA Firewall Can PING cannot SSH to switch on different interface

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall, access-control

There are three interfaces, TRUST (security level 100), UNTRUST (security level 0), and DMZ (security level 50).

I am on a network coming into the firewall via the UNTRUST interface.  The switch I am able to use ICMP with but not SSH to (timeout) is connected via the DMZ interface.  There are three rules which each included the same service group (including icmp, tcp/ssh, udp/tftp, tcp/telnet, udp/syslog).  These rules are applied as follows:

```
DMZ Interface (incoming)
    DMZ_network any IP permit

TRUST Interface (incoming)
    DMZ_switch my_laptop service_group permit

UNTRUST Interface (incoming)
    my_laptop DMZ_switch service_group permit
```

So I am able to ICMP, and I see increment on the rules that have been applied, but I receive connection-timeout for SSH connection attempts.  I've spent too much time hitting my head on the proverbial wall to not reach out for an assist here.  I appreciate anyone and everyone who takes time to read or answer this question.

Regards,
lzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your ruleset is correct... Have you checked on the switch side? There might be an access-class configured on your vty.

p.s. you may want to use packet-tracer on ASA to check if traffic would be permited or just check the logbuffer via CLI/ASDM to see what is really going on.

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have an ACL in the OUT direction for the DMZ interface.

Traffic will enter the untrusted interface for which you have an ACL - fine
Then traffic will exit (out) the DMZ interface where the switch management is.

Hence why you need to permit "laptop_ip dmz_switch any_service_you_want"

You do not need to worry about the "return" traffic as the ASA will keep the state

Let me know if it is clear what I wrote above

Regards
Ravi

Comment: None of the interfaces have OUTGOING access rules set and I am able to successfully authenticate to and access other switches.

Comment: In that case, you may want to check if ssh is properly configured on that switch (that is, hostname, key etc). Alternatively type "debug ssh" to see what is going on